# How to search in h2 database Play Framework 2.7.3?

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I need to search in an h2 database for `Company` class instances that have a specific `code`, but I can't figure out how.

I have tried using the Finder class, but there don't seem to be any find methods in the version i am using except `findbyid()`.
Here is the beginning of my Company class:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Model {
    @Id
    public Integer id;
    public String code;
    public String name;
    public String adress;
    public String fiscalCode;
    public String bankAccount;

    public static Finder<Integer, Company> find = new Finder<>(Company.class);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Play you are using I'd suggest to try the following:

`Company.find.where().like("code", "%foo%").findList();`

or

1. Define your finder

```
public class CompanyFinder extends Finder<Long,Company> {

  public CompanyFinder() {
    super(Company.class);
  }

  // Add finder methods ...

  public Company byCode(String code) {
    return query().eq("code", code).findOne();
  }
}
```

2. Update your entity to reference this finder:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends BaseModel {

  public static final CompanyFinder find = new CompanyFinder();
  ...
}
```

3. Call the finder:

`Company c = Company.find.byCode("foo");`